# How to pass hash map object to http outbound in mule?

Tags: http, mule

I need to pass hash map object to Http outbound using post method in mule.

How can it be done?

Comment: What is the  exact error which you are facing. Usually whatever the payload which you are passing before HTTP outbound ( Make the method as post(General->Method->POST in HTTP). It should work.

Comment: yes, i am using Post method, but the problem my payload will a map consisting map values(map within a map), so i should pass the entire map values to the HTTP Outbound.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this can help

```
<flow name="demoFlow1" doc:name="demoFlow1">
    <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="8081" path="hi" doc:name="HTTP"/>
    <scripting:component doc:name="Groovy">
        <scripting:script engine="Groovy">
            <scripting:text><![CDATA[
                Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                map.put("name", "Eddu");
                map.put("lastname", "Melendez");
                return map;

            ]]></scripting:text>

        </scripting:script>
    </scripting:component>
    <http:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="8081" path="print" method="POST" doc:name="HTTP"/>        
</flow>
<flow name="demoFlow2" doc:name="demoFlow2">
    <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="8081" path="print" doc:name="HTTP"/>
    <logger level="INFO" message="#[message.payloadAs(java.lang.String)]" doc:name="Logger"/>
</flow>
```

This will be the output if you send a map through the service:

INFO  2015-01-22 08:30:42,298 [[demo].connector.http.mule.default.receiver.03] org.mule.api.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: **name=Eddu&lastname=Melendez**

You can also add the line below, in order to get a json instead query params in http

As you can see the response will be different

INFO  2015-01-22 08:32:31,014 [[demo].connector.http.mule.default.receiver.03] org.mule.api.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: **{"name":"Eddu","lastname":"Melendez"}**

Comment: thanks, I knew this, but i need a map within a map(a map consisting map values). and i need to pass the entire map values to the http outbound.

Comment: Do yo men something like this?

`Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
map.put("name", "Eddu");
map.put("lastname", "Melendez");
Map<String, Object> address = new HashMap<String, Object>();
address.put("city", "Lima");
address.put("country", "Peru");
address.put("postalCode", "051");
map.put("address", address);`